# What can be used to create a unique URL for a user's public page?

Tags: website-design, users, urls

Many websites use the form `https://www.example.com/username` as the unique URL to a user's public page. For example, Jeff Atwood's public twitter feed is at https://twitter.com/codinghorror.

What other options are there for a unique user-friendly URL for a user's public page?

Comment: This is like asking what the best color is to paint your walls.

Comment: I'm asking for options, especially those I may not have thought of, for creating a unique URL, which is objective. I'm not asking what is better or best, which would be subjective.

Comment: You always have the option to generate a random string which can be used as public identifier

Answer (score 2):

You don't have much of choices here, pal:

1) `https://www.example.com/any-kind-of-data`

1) `https://www.any-kind-of-data.example.com/`

`any-kind-of-data` can be anything you like.

Comment: I prefer the first option, especially as you can do "creative" things like www.facebook.com/default.aspx :^)

Comment: True thing, but the UX is all about context. So, even though it's kind of intuitively more friendly and flexible to you, it's not only about you and/or facebook :) For example, a "`user's public page`" can be a page of some web-hosting company, offering its service(hosting) for free(or whatever), and considering this you may actually prefer a sub-domain and not an example.com/your-page-name URL. So it's really depend on the context

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best possible option to keep URL unique and user friendly.

But only disadvantage I see in this case is, **user is forced to find his unique username**. I mean that if a username is already taken then user will be pissed while signing up (If this repeats say a 100 times :P ).

one more method would be to let user have his fun with his username and you append a UID after the username. ex. **somesite.com/crazyusername-xxxx123uid** so user will be happy!., but again in this case URL will not be as user friendly as in first case.

generally sites that make heavy use of usernames as primary source of users identity go for the first one. best example would be **online gaming sites**!. second one would make sense if it is not the case ex. **linkedin** uses this type of URL for public pages.

So choose your battle and decide. hope this helps.